# Replacing TinyMCE fonts within WordPress editor - default fon't won't go away

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to replace the list of available fonts shown in WordPress' editor so that it only shows relevant fonts for the site, but even though I only include two custom fonts in the list the default one still shows up, that being "Georgia".

However, it's weird that it doesn't show up as a "selectable option", as in, it's the first option, but doesn't show in the actual dropdown.

**My code:**

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'blm_load_custom_fonts');

function blm_load_custom_fonts($init) {
    $init['font_formats'] = 'Poppins=Poppins, sans-serif;Tex Gyre Adventor=Tex Gyre Adventor, sans-serif';
    return $init;
}
```

**Here is what I see:**

[image]

How can I get rid of Georgia and make "Poppins" the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load content into TinyMCE that select list will show the font in use where the cursor is located.  If you click to see the content of the select list that should only show you the fonts you have configured to be an option.

It is hard to tell from your screenshot but it looks like the default text in the editor is indeed Georgia font?

This is how TinyMCE works and you can't disable that behavior.

***UPDATE***:  To address your question on the "default" font.  I would suspect WordPress allows you to determine the default font in use while creating content. 
 There is a configuration setting for TinyMCE called `content_css` that allows you to pass in CSS that determines how things are rendered.  Guessing WordPress already uses some sort of CSS (possibly theme related) that you would need to modify to change the default.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. I tested it and see what you mean :) However, when you start a new post for example it will show Georgia as an option and obviously use that as the default - so there is no way to change that behavior to using "Poppins" for example?

Comment: @Brett - see edit above regarding the "default" font quesiton.

Comment: Thanks. I have no issues changing the default font used on the actual rendered pages, I was just wanting to, if possible, have the TinyMCE one changed so there was no need to show "Georgia" as an option unless there was any text using it, so then all new posts would default to "Poppins" - this is just a visual thing for the backend.